# Azure Instance hung after changing from Extra small to Small virtual machine size

Tags: azure

The instance has hung or hasn't responded for about 3 hour. It writes "UPDATE IN PROGRESS There is an update operation in progress. You will be able to adjust configuration settings once it completes." in the preview UI. And statuses in the old UI are "Waiting for host..." for the instance and "Initializing..." for the role.

How can I resurrect the instance? The only action available is delete. Should i delete the instance and create a new one using the same storage but why there is ability to change sizes then?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ability to restart/reboot instance from portal please do so, something during migration the VM get stuck and you can recover by rebooting however sometimes these options are disabled at portal so you can not do anything.

IF you have no visible way to recover your instance, you have ability to delete the VM and create a new VM from the same OS VHD. This is a known issues and this suggestion was given time to time. Hopefully after the preview feature this problem will be resolved.

Comment: Have deleted the old instance (it wasn't responding for 7 hours) and created a new one using the old VHD.

Comment: Great. During preview this is the problem, impacting most of the users and hope things will improve further on.